# Problema de código

Tags: javascript, html

Meu código de adivinhação está funcionando, porém, ao invés de dar apenas 3 tentativas para o usuário, o programa dá 4 tentativas. Como faço para o código parar na terceira tentativa ??

```js
var chute = document.getElementById("chute")
var tentativa = document.getElementById("tentativa")
tentativa.innerText = 3 //Valor que irá aparecer na tela

function valida() {
  var chute2 = parseInt(chute.value) //Declarar como variável local para não resetar o valor
  var tentativa2 = parseInt(tentativa.innerText)
  if (chute2 >= 0 && chute2 <= 10) {
    aleatorio(chute2, tentativa2)
  } else {
    alert("Favor digitar um numero de 0 a 10")
  }
}

function aleatorio(chute2, tentativa2) {
  var numero = parseInt(1 + Math.random() * 10)

  if (chute2 != numero && tentativa2 != 0) { //colocar o tentativa != 0 para não entrar em "loop infinito"
    alert("Você errou! Tente de novo")
    tentativa2-- //Reduz o valor int
    tentativa.innerText = tentativa2 //O innerText é atribuido ao seu novo valor convertido em int
    document.getElementById("chute").value = "" //Limpa a caixa de diálogo

  } else if (chute2 != numero && tentativa2 == 0) {
    alert("Suas chances acabaram! O número correto é " + numero)
    window.location.reload()
  } else if (chute2 == numero) {
    alert("Parabéns! Você acertou")
    window.location.reload()
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Adivinhador</h1>
<p>
  Seu chute: <br>
  <input type="text" id="chute" name="chute">
</p>

<button onclick="valida()" reset="true">Arriscar</button>

<p>Tentativas: <span id="tentativa"></span> </p>
<!-- Para converter valor de span no JS, chamar o innerText -->
```

Comment: Coloca `tentativa2-- //Reduz o valor int` antes do `if`.

Comment: Acho que eh isso mesmo

Comment: Sim, resolveu meu problema

Obrigado

Comment: @bcastro95 Marca a resposta do Sérgio como correta. Usando o **V** do lado esquerdo da mesma.

Comment: não adianta apenas diminuir o `tentativa2` se não remover a frase de "suas chances acabaram" do else if, ou vai receber a mensagem de que errou, ou de que as tentativas acabaram, tirando que ele ira pular a ultima, começando em 3, ele teria apenas a 2 e 1 para responder

Answer (score 1):

Você usou um else if para verificar se a opção está certa, voce pode verificar em todas as tentativas se as tentativas acabaram

```js
var chute = document.getElementById("chute")
var tentativa = document.getElementById("tentativa")
tentativa.innerText = 3 //Valor que irá aparecer na tela

function valida() {
  var chute2 = parseInt(chute.value) //Declarar como variável local para não resetar o valor
  var tentativa2 = parseInt(tentativa.innerText)
  if (chute2 >= 0 && chute2 <= 10) {
    aleatorio(chute2, tentativa2)
  } else {
    alert("Favor digitar um numero de 0 a 10")
  }
}

function aleatorio(chute2, tentativa2) {
  var numero = parseInt(1 + Math.random() * 10)

  if (chute2 != numero && tentativa2 != 0) { //colocar o tentativa != 0 para não entrar em "loop infinito"
    alert("Você errou! Tente de novo")
    tentativa2-- //Reduz o valor int
    tentativa.innerText = tentativa2 //O innerText é atribuido ao seu novo valor convertido em int
    document.getElementById("chute").value = "" //Limpa a caixa de diálogo

  } 
  if (chute2 != numero && tentativa2 == 0) {
    alert("Suas chances acabaram! O número correto é " + numero)
    window.location.reload()
  } else if (chute2 == numero) {
    alert("Parabéns! Você acertou")
    window.location.reload()
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Adivinhador</h1>
<p>
  Seu chute: <br>
  <input type="text" id="chute" name="chute">
</p>

<button onclick="valida()" reset="true">Arriscar</button>

<p>Tentativas: <span id="tentativa"></span> </p>
<!-- Para converter valor de span no JS, chamar o innerText -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Se percebi bem, cada vez que o código entrar em `aleatorio` perde uma tentativa.

Então o `tentativa2--` deve estar logo à entrada dessa função, antes do `if` que verifica quantas tentativas faltam.

```
function aleatorio(chute2, tentativa2) {
    var numero = parseInt(1 + Math.random() * 10);
    tentativa2--; //Reduz o valor int
    if (chute2 != numero && tentativa2 != 0) { //colocar o tentativa != 0 para não entrar em "loop infinito"
        // etc...
```